# Regarding Region of Convergence in Z-Transform

Tags: summation, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, z-transform

I am trying to understand Region of Convergence (RoC) of Z-transform.

If $x(n) = a^n u(n)$ then its z-transform is given as

$X(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x(n) z^{-n} = \sum_{0}^{\infty}a(n) z^{-n}$. This expression can be further written as:

$X(z)= \sum_{0}^{\infty} (az^{-1})^n$ ---(1)

For convergence of $X(z)$, we require that summation in eq.(1) should be lesser than $\infty$, i.e.,

$\sum_{0}^{\infty} (az^{-1})^n < \infty$ ---(2)

I had understood both eq.(1) and eq. (2).

However, in some of the text it is written that "Consequently, RoC is that range of values of $z$ for which $|az^{-1}|< 1$".

My query is that, I am not getting how $|az^{-1}|< 1$ comes into the picture, especially after eq. (2).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem).

Comment: Ok Thank you sir...